# Constraints get invalidated

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, tableview

I'm trying to create a table view cell with a UILabel and a UIImageView.

Here's a screenshot of my view controller when it opens.

[image]

When I scroll the cell out of the view or when I tap on the cell, the image view's frame changes.

[image]

[image]

Here are my constraints:

[image]

Here are my dataSource methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    let currentVolume = viewModel.volumes?[indexPath.row];

    if let volume = currentVolume {
        if (volume.isPurchased == 0) {
            let reuseIdentiifier = Constants.ReuseIdentifier.VolumeListTableViewCellReuseId;
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentiifier, for: indexPath) as! VolumeTableViewCell;
            cell.setTitle(title: (volume.name));
            return cell;
        }
        else {
            let reuseIdentiifier = Constants.ReuseIdentifier.LockedVolumeListTableViewCellReuseId;
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentiifier, for: indexPath) as! LockedVolumeTableViewCell;
            cell.setTitle(title: (volume.name));
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
return UITableViewCell.init();
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    //Disables the 'selected' cell
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true);
}
```

I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: @AamirR That doesn't help. Also I need to constrain the title label's trailing to 15 points before the image view.

Comment: What's wrong in using it the way I have?

Ideally, what I'd want is:

1) trailing = Imageview.trailing + 15
2) label.trailing = imageView.leading - 15
3) imageView.width = 20

Comment: Your constraints looks fine. It seems to be a problem in your code rather. Could you share your code where you construct and set up your cell?

Comment: @LGP I've edited the post to include my setup code.

Comment: When the lock "jumps", open the View Debugger and see if it has any warnings for you.

Comment: [Also you need to stop using semicolons, unnecessary parentheses, etc.; Swift is not C!]

Comment: Are your reuse identifier constants by mistake same?

Comment: @LGP No, already checked that. I had a suggestion to use stackView instead and that solution worked. But I'm really keen on figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: @KunalShah strange, Do one thing, remove all constrain and add again one by one.

Answer (score 0):

First select imageView and add constraints selected in screen shot [image]

and also add "Vertically center constraint"

then select label and add constraints selected in screen short [image]

hope this will work if any problem let me know.